# How to change the device name in Google Play (formerly Android Market)?

Tags: google-play-store

I have bought a new phone and need to change the old device name to the new one. How do I change the device name in Google Play (formerly Android Market)?

Comment: What is a device name?

Comment: Where do you want to see the change in your device name? Are you referring to the device list in the Google Play Store website?

Comment: @Mihir It has a market tag so I guess not

Answer (score 27):

Log in to the web interface of the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) and click the settings button in the top right corner and select `My Orders and Settings` (or use this [direct link](https://play.google.com/store/account)). Next, select the `Settings` tab and you'll see your devices. From here, just click on `Edit` and type the name you wish to give the device and click `Update`.

Comment: Great!! I didn't think about that!!